# Get duplicated rows in one column with different values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame:

```
A = data.frame(a = c("q", "e", "f", "q"), b = 1:4)
```

I want to get 2 rows (duplicated q in a, with different values, 1,4 in b)

Comment: Can you paste some code of what you have tried?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the desired exact output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the function `duplicated`:

```
A[A$a %in% A$a[duplicated(A$a)],]
#   a b
# 1 q 1
# 4 q 4
```

This will give you any row containing a value of a found 2 or more times in the data.frame.

@Sotos proposed this, it's 20% faster on 100.000 rows:

```
A[duplicated(A$a)|duplicated(A$a, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

@mohamed-nidabdella proposed this solution with dplyr which is 2.5 times faster:

```
A %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(n()>1)
```

The benchmark:

```
A = data.frame(a =sample(letters,100000,replace=TRUE), b = 1:100000)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  a = A[A$a %in% A$a[duplicated(A$a)],],
  b =A[duplicated(A$a)|duplicated(A$a, fromLast = TRUE),],
  c = A[A$a %in% unique(A$a[duplicated(A$a)]),],
  d = A %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(n()>1),
  times=100)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
# a 23.549739 24.732701 27.71688 27.70747 28.463392 115.58251   100
# b 20.703155 21.485692 24.66477 21.79380 24.790283 113.42992   100
# c 23.215580 24.166518 26.83627 24.99078 27.824526 113.99780   100
# d  8.647365  9.099141 10.17412  9.25546  9.548462  46.96581   100
```

Comment: If that is the case then also, `A[duplicated(A$a)|duplicated(A$a, fromLast = TRUE),]`

Comment: May I just add that, if this is the output the OP wants then, it can be achieved using`dplyr` package : `A %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(n()>1)`

Comment: @Sotos thanks it's a bit faster, I added it to the answer

Comment: Thanks @mohamed-nidabdella, i added it as well

Comment: The way the benchmark data are created guarantees that each letter will appear at least 10  times. So the fastest solution would be simply to return `A`.

Comment: there was a typo, i had put 10000 instead of 100000, i changed it but it doesn't change anything in the end. I don't understand what you mean by simply returning A.

Answer (score 0):

```
library("data.table")
setDT(A)
rbind(A, A[a == "q", .(a, b = c(1, 4))])
#    a b
# 1: q 1
# 2: e 2
# 3: f 3
# 4: q 4
# 5: q 1
# 6: q 4
```